# How to add dll file for windows phone app certification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I use slartoolkit.dll file for windows augmented reality. It working well in my mobile(Nokia Lumia 510) and emulator. then i will send that xap file only to windows phone Store  Certification center but test Result is Fail. I don't know what mistake i did.

please any one give me a suggestion

Comment: What was the failure for your certification?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact error the certification gave you it's hard to say why it failed. I have 25+ apps published and its RARE that I get an app to pass cert on the first time. There is always something small that you miss. A back button crash, forgetting to shut off sound, color settings wrong. There's endless possibilities.

That said, you need to check that the dll is certified for the windows phone. I know that I recently tried to implement a Physics Helper dll just to find out that unsigned dlls are no longer authorized on the windows phone. I believe that it died out with the release of 7.5 but I could be wrong.

Hopefully this gives you some insight and answers your question. Your best bet though is to post the certification failure PDF they sent you. Look in the email it should be attached.

Until there here is some reading material. [Microsoft Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184843%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also try using the built in certification tests within [Visual Studio Market Test Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)